# Processing large images with Sharp on Lambda@Edge

Tags: serverless-framework, sharp, aws-lambda-edge

When using Sharp in a function deployed to Lambda@Edge I'm getting the following error:

`vips__write: write failed unix error: No space left on device`

Running on Lambda, this can be fixed using the VIPS_DISC_THRESHOLD env variable, but since env variable are not allowed for Lambda@Edge I'm looking for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 1):

This solved it for me:

`process.env.VIPS_DISC_THRESHOLD = '750m'`